# Access Duals for Variable Bounds in Pyomo

Tags: pyomo

Is it possible to access dual information related to the variable bounds in Pyomo? For constraints, you can declare a Suffix, but is there an equivalent for the variable bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a suffix named `rc` (reduced cost) to obtain this from the following interfaces:

- Gurobi: LP, MPS, Python
- Cplex: LP, MPS, Python
- Glpk: LP, MPS

Xpress might also be on that list, but I have no way of verifying that.

The Gurobi and Cplex solvers for AMPL do not return this information as suffixes (and I don't know why), so you can not get these through the NL-file interface to these solvers in Pyomo.

Also, for Ipopt you can get this by declaring suffixes named `ipopt_zL_out` and `ipopt_zU_out` for the duals of the lower bounds and upper bounds, respectively. See [this](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/examples/pyomo/suffixes/ipopt_warmstart.py) example for a better explanation.

The above list is only what I am aware of. There are likely other AMPL solvers that provide this information through suffixes, so you would be able to access that solution information through Pyomo's NL-file interface as long is you know the name of the suffix.

Update: Here is an example with gurobi:

```py
import pyomo.environ as aml

model = aml.ConcreteModel()
model.x = aml.Var(bounds=(0,1))
model.o = aml.Objective(expr=model.x)
model.c = aml.Constraint(expr=model.x >= -1)

model.rc = aml.Suffix(direction=aml.Suffix.IMPORT)

gurobi = aml.SolverFactory("gurobi",
                           solver_io="lp")
results = gurobi.solve(model)
assert str(results.solver.termination_condition) == "optimal"

print(model.rc[model.x])
```

As I explained above, you can set `solver_io` in this example to "lp", "mps", or "python" with Gurobi.

Comment: can you also give a example with a variable for e.g gurobi?